# Who is the best software engineering teacher you know? what makes them the best?

Tags: lesson-ideas, best-practice, lecture-tools

Looking to find some of the best teachers in software engineering; not the best computer scientists or software engineers per se. But those who train and develop software engineers that and build great software in the industry. I'd like to learn about what they do that makes them a great teacher. I've found [Uncle Bob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin) to be one of the best but who else? I'd appreciate some resources as well.

Comment: The question is interesting and the purpose seems good. However, the format isn't a good for for the site. You might join the, usually slow chatroom.

Comment: It is also badly tagged, but I can't think of better tags and don't recommend creating new ones here.

Comment: And, of course, many of us want to answer: me, me, me. ;-)

Comment: I don't think there's an objective way to assess educators to make this not opinion-based. It's a simple question and you get the idea. How would I change it to make it answerable?